# How to hide more than one drive using regedit

Tags: windows, windows-registry

Normally we can hide drives using regedit. But its possible to hide only one drive when i tried to hide another drive an error showing that the registry key name is already exist. if there any ways to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're referring to the NoDrives settings, as described in the Microsoft KnowledgeBase article "[Hide physical drives in Windows Explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555438)", what you would do is add the values together.  For example, if you want to hide the E and G drives, you'd add the value for the E drive (10 00 00 00) and the value for the G drive (40 00 00 00) to get 50 00 00 00.  Setting the NoDrives value to 50 00 00 00 should hide both of them.

For reference, here are the steps to set that registry value:

1. Go to Windows registry Editor.
2. Navigate to the following path:
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
3. In the right-pane, create a new Binary entry "NoDrives"
4. Enter the corresponding binary value - in this case to hide E and G you would enter 50 00 00 00. The full list of values is in the linked article.
5. Save and restart Windows.

Note: This applies to Windows XP. I'm not sure about other versions of Windows.

Comment: If u want to hide more than 1 drive suppose C:\ & D:\, we know the value of C:\=4 and D:\=8. So addition the values of C:\ & D:\ (4+8=12). Put this in "NnDrives" as a decimal value. Then restart your PC and you can see that your Drives will be hidden.

Comment: You can also calculate the correct decimal value using [this online tool](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-nodrives.html).